# Careers, buttons in my profile

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs

I would like the buttons (tag buttons) in my Career profile to be clickable.

Clicking on the `C#` button should show all my questions and answers for `C#`

Comment: Good idea, stand by...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks, this has been implemented.

Comment: It seems only the ones in the header are clickable now... Would it be possible to do that with the others as well? (the ones in "Likes", in individual experiences, etc...)

Comment: We chose only to do the ones in the header, since that data is pulled directly from SO. The ones in the "likes" area don't necessarily have a relationship to your Stack Overflow answers, so linking them would be hit-or-miss.

Comment: Answers of the form "Thamks..." are discouraged. That is what upvotes and accepting are for.  In this case, the 'Status-completed' tag serves nicely.